# Out of order results returned calling jdbc stored procedure with callablestatement

Tags: xml, jdbc, plsqldeveloper, clob, callable-statement

i have a stored procedure in my database that returns a clob with xml data representation.

My problem is when i test the procedure from pl/sql developer iam getting the results in order.

On the other hand when i call the procedure with Java CallableStatement it returns me the results of the xml in incorrect order.

This happens when i have more than 12 elements in my xml. When i have less than 12 elements the results are correct and in order both in the output of the procedure and in output of the call in Java.

I need to get the same results in order both in the testing of the procedure in the database and in Java Call.

My result from the procedure

```
<Picking>1164
    <Items Count="26">
        <Item Index="1">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="052058100000010576">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K01.007.00A.004</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>184</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">184</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">184</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="2">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="052058100000010620">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K01.007.00A.004</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>193</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">193</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">193</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="3">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="052058100000010590">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K01.007.00B.004</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>193</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">193</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">193</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="4">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="052058100000010606">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K01.007.00B.004</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>177</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">177</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">177</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="5">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="052058100000010545">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K01.007.00B.005</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>185</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">185</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">185</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="6">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="052058100000010569">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K01.007.00B.005</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>170</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">170</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">170</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="7">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="052058100000010538">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K01.007.00A.006</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>170</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">170</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">170</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="8">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="052058100000010521">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K01.007.00A.006</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>175</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">175</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">175</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="9">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="052058100000010491">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K01.007.00B.006</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>200</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">200</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">200</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="10">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="052058100000010484">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K01.007.00A.007</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>180</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">180</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">180</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="11">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="052058100000010460">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K01.007.00B.007</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>196</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">196</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">196</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="12">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="052058100000010453">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K01.007.00B.007</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>193</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">193</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">193</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="13">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="052058100000010330">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K01.007.00C.001</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>141</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">141</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">170</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="14">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="552058100006300546">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K21.004.00D.002</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>249</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">249</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">249</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="15">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="552058100006300614">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K21.008.00A.005</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>320</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">320</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">320</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="16">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="152058100005319435">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K22.001.00D.002</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>310</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">310</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">310</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="17">
            <Code Description="ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΦΥΛΛΟ ΙQF ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΗΜΙΕ ΒΙΝS"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="152058100005319428">09.001.000.B10</Code>
            <LocatedAt>K22.016.00A.001</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>3456</Requested>
            <Allocated>220</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">220</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">220</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="18">
            <Code Description="SΤRΕΤCΗ FΙLΜ SFM  17micro  NANAO ΒΙΟΜΗΧΑΝΙΚΟ"
                  BMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΚΙΛ"
                  SSCC="152058100007572807">81.007.000.002</Code>
            <LocatedAt>AYL.001.001.001</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>1</Requested>
            <Allocated>1</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">1</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΚΙΛ">321</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="19">
            <Code Description="ΣΑΚΟΥΛΕΣ ΑΤΥΠΩΤΕΣ ΣΙΕΛ ΣΚΟΥΠΙΔΙΑ LD 90-60*65/6 (για τελαρα)"
                  BMU="ΤΕΜ"
                  SMU="ΚΙΛ"
                  LU="ΤΕΜ"
                  SSCC="252058100007016056">81.111.000.003</Code>
            <LocatedAt>AYL.001.001.001</LocatedAt>
            <Requested SMU=".471">8</Requested>
            <Allocated SMU=".471">8</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">8</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">14280</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="20">
            <Code Description="ΤΑΙΝΙΕΣ ΜΠΛΕ-ΑCRΥLΙC  48Χ600Μ"
                  BMU="ΤΕΜ"
                  LU="ΤΕΜ"
                  SSCC="252058100006421219">81.112.000.004</Code>
            <LocatedAt>AYL.001.001.001</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>1</Requested>
            <Allocated>1</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">1</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">840</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="21">
            <Code Description="ΕΤΙΚΕΤΑ ΛΕΥΚΗ ΘΕΡΜΙΚΗ 105Χ75 ΜΡ ΜΕΓΑΛΟ ΜΑΔΡΕΝ  RETAIL BAGS-ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΝΩΠΟ"
                  BMU="ΤΕΜ"
                  LU="ΤΕΜ"
                  SSCC="252058100007615747">81.114.000.002</Code>
            <LocatedAt>AYL.001.001.001</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>432</Requested>
            <Allocated>432</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">432</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">120000</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="22">
            <Code Description="ΕΤΙΚΕΤΑ ΛΕΥΚΗ ΘΕΡΜΙΚΗ 105Χ75 ΜΡ ΜΕΓΑΛΟ ΜΑΔΡΕΝ  RETAIL BAGS-ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΝΩΠΟ"
                  BMU="ΤΕΜ"
                  LU="ΤΕΜ"
                  SSCC="252058100007615747">81.114.000.002</Code>
            <LocatedAt>AYL.001.001.001</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>432</Requested>
            <Allocated>432</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">432</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">24000</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="23">
            <Code Description="ΕΤΙΚΕΤΑ ΛΕΥΚΗ ΘΕΡΜΙΚΗ 105Χ75 ΜΡ ΜΕΓΑΛΟ ΜΑΔΡΕΝ  RETAIL BAGS-ΣΠΑΝΑΚΙ ΝΩΠΟ"
                  BMU="ΤΕΜ"
                  LU="ΤΕΜ"
                  SSCC="252058100007615747">81.114.000.002</Code>
            <LocatedAt>AYL.001.001.001</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>432</Requested>
            <Allocated>432</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">432</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">78000</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="24">
            <Code Description="ΕΤΙΚΕΤΑ ΛΕΥΚΗ ΘΕΡΜΙΚΗ 150Χ210 BAR CODE"
                  BMU="ΤΕΜ"
                  LU="ΤΕΜ"
                  SSCC="252058100007415521">81.114.000.003</Code>
            <LocatedAt>AYL.001.001.001</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>8</Requested>
            <Allocated>8</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">8</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">50302</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="25">
            <Code Description="Χ/Κ  ΦΥΛΛΑ  0,80*1,20 EURO ΠΑΛΕΤΑΣ"
                  BMU="ΤΕΜ"
                  LU="ΤΕΜ"
                  SSCC="252058100007109482">83.110.000.005</Code>
            <LocatedAt>DIA.001.001.001</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>8</Requested>
            <Allocated>8</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">8</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">450</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
        <Item Index="26">
            <Code Description="Χ/Κ  383*248*273 441 GR 15ΚG NORMAL ΓΕΝΙΚΟ ΛΑΧΑΝΙΚΩΝ"
                  BMU="ΤΕΜ"
                  LU="ΤΕΜ"
                  SSCC="252058100007367103">83.110.000.007</Code>
            <LocatedAt>DIA.001.001.001</LocatedAt>
            <Requested>432</Requested>
            <Allocated>432</Allocated>
            <AllocatedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">432</AllocatedLU>
            <ContainedLU LU="ΤΕΜ">880</ContainedLU>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</Picking>
```

And my Java Code

```
public ProductSuggestionMasterBean getProductContents64(int 
        usage, String username, long pickingListId,
        String panel) throws DataBaseException {
    try (Connection conn = controlEjb.getConnection(em);
            CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call MOM_WAREHOUSE.TERMINAL_PCG.Module064Get(?,?)}")) {
        controlEjb.InitERP(usage, username);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.CLOB);
        cstmt.setLong(2, pickingListId);
        cstmt.setString(3, panel);
        cstmt.execute();
        final Clob clob = cstmt.getClob(1);
        if (clob == null || clob.length() == 0L) {
            throw new DataBaseException("ΣΦΑΛΜΑ: Δεν βρέθηκαν πληροφορίες για το picking list" + pickingListId);
        }
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(clob.getCharacterStream())) {
            final DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            final Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(br));
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            final ProductSuggestionMasterBean result = new ProductSuggestionMasterBean();

            // Set Product sugggestions.
            final Long itemCount = ((Number) xpath.compile("//Items/@Count").evaluate(document,
                    XPathConstants.NUMBER)).longValue();
            final List<ProductSuggestionBean> details = new ArrayList<>(itemCount.intValue());

            final int order = ((Number) xpath.compile("Response//Item/@Index").evaluate(document,
                    XPathConstants.NUMBER)).intValue();

            for (long i = order; i <= itemCount; i++) {
                final ProductSuggestionBean suggestion = new ProductSuggestionBean();
                try {

                    suggestion.setId(((Number) xpath.compile("Response/Picking/text()").evaluate(document,
                            XPathConstants.NUMBER)).longValue());

                    suggestion.setItemDescription((String) xpath
                            .compile("Response/Picking/Items/Item[" + i + "][@Index=" + i + "]/Code/@Description")
                            .evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING));

                    suggestion.setItem((String) xpath
                            .compile("Response/Picking/Items/Item[" + i + "][@Index=" + i + "]/Code/text()")
                            .evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING));

                    suggestion.setPanelDescription((String) xpath
                            .compile("Response/Picking/Items/Item[" + i + "][@Index=" + i + "]/LocatedAt/text()")
                            .evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING));
                    try {
                        BigDecimal pUnitValue = new BigDecimal(
                                TextUtils.reverseDecimalSeparator((String) xpath
                                        .compile("Response/Picking/Items/Item[" + i + "][@Index=" + i
                                                + "]/ContainedLU/text()")
                                        .evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING)));

                        String pUnitDsc = ((String) xpath
                                .compile("Response/Picking/Items/Item[" + i + "][@Index=" + i + "]/Code/@LU")
                                .evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING));
                        BigDecimal sUnitValue = new BigDecimal(
                                TextUtils.reverseDecimalSeparator((String) xpath
                                        .compile("Response/Picking/Items/Item[" + i + "][@Index=" + i
                                                + "]/AllocatedLU/text()")
                                        .evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING)));
                        suggestion.setPrimaryMeasurementUnit(new MeasurementUnitBean(pUnitValue, pUnitDsc));

                        String sUnitDsc = ((String) xpath
                                .compile("Response/Picking/Items/Item[" + i + "][@Index=" + i + "]/Code/@LU")
                                .evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING));
                        suggestion.setSecondaryMeasurementUnit(new MeasurementUnitBean(sUnitValue, sUnitDsc));
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                    }

                    try {
                        suggestion.setSscc((String) xpath
                                .compile("Response/Picking/Items/Item[" + i + "][@Index=" + i + "]/Code/@SSCC")
                                .evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING));
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                    }

                    details.add(suggestion);
                } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            result.setSuggestions(details);
            clob.free();
            return result;
        }
    } catch (SQLException | ParserConfigurationException | IndexOutOfBoundsException | IOException
            | NullPointerException | NumberFormatException | SAXException | XPathExpressionException e) {
        controlEjb.printErrorTrace(e, null);
        throw new DataBaseException(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should include more details in your question (use Edit button). Specifically show the procedure code and how you invoke it from java and get the result. Without this information it is hard to tell what is wrong.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA sorry, you are right, i edited it and put some extra info, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Replacing ORDER BY ID in the sql query that sorts the elements with ORDER BY NLSSORT(ID, 'NLS_SORT = UNICODE_BINARY') fixes the issue.